# Unable to set SCSS variable to CSS variable?

Tags: css, sass

Consider the following SCSS:

```
$color-black: #000000;

body {
    --color: $color-black;
}
```

When it is compiled with node-sass **version 4.7.2**, it produces following CSS:

```
body {
    --color: #000000; 
}
```

When I compile the same SCSS with version **4.8.3 or higher**, it produces following:

```
body {
    --color: $color-black; 
}
```

**What am I missing?** I checked release logs, but could not found anything useful. Also, I wonder if this change is genuine why does it have only minor version change? Should it not be a major release?

Also, **what is my alternative?** Should I use **Interpolation**?

Comment: Yup, use string interpolation, i.e. `--color: #{$color-black};`. See: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2336

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Just use string interpolation:

```
$color-black: #000000;

body {
    --color: #{$color-black};
}
```

Apparently the old behaviour is not intended and violated the language specs of SASS:

- [CSS variables mixed with SCSS variables don't emit proper CSS in 4.8+](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2336)
- [CSS variables aren't properly compiled](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1943#issuecomment-379747451)
- [Assigning SASS variables to CSS Variables (Custom Properties) no longer works](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/2621)

Answer (score 14):

## scss and css

I found a workaround to mapping the scss variables to css variables.

See Terry's answer for better use

Scss:

```
// sass variable map 
$colors: (
  color-black: #FFBB00
);

// loop over each name, color
:root {
  // each item in color map
  @each $name, $color in $colors {
    --#{$name}: #{$color};
  }
}
```

Css:

```
:root {
  --color-black: #FFBB00;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with older sass versions.

Trying to compile a list of variables coming from an array, it would get stuck with the double dash.  Here's my solution in case it helps someone

```
$var-element:'--';

:root {
    @each $color in $color-variables {
     #{$var-element}#{nth($color, 1)}: #{nth($color, 2)};   
    }
}
```