# My SASS variables into :root are not interpolated

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

I'm fairly new to the Nuxt ecosystem. Awesome package that makes our lives much easier.

I'm trying to add `sass` to my project. After following the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-css) my build runs perfectly but my `scss` files are not being compiled. An example of the problem:

[image]

Notice that `--thm-font` is set to `$primaryTypography` and not the actual value from the `.scss`.

I'm expecting to see `--thm-font: 'Barlow', sans-serif`. I'm assuming that the `sass` is not being compiled. It is important to note I'm not looking for a component base style but I'm trying to have a `main.scss` where I will import the component, layouts and many other styles.

### _variables.scss

```
// Base colors
$base: #ee464b;
$baseRgb: (238, 70, 75);
$black: #272839;
$blackRgb: (39, 40, 57);
$grey: #f4f4f8;

// Typography
$primaryTypography: 'Barlow', sans-serif;

@debug $primaryTypography; // -> this one outputs the correct value

:root {
  --thm-font: $primaryTypography;
  --thm-base: $base;
  --thm-base-rgb: $baseRgb;
  --thm-black: $black;
  --thm-black-rgb: $blackRgb;
  --thm-gray: $grey;
}
```

### nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  css: [
    '~assets/scss/main.scss'
  ],
  plugins: [
  ],
  buildModules: [
  ],
  modules: [
  ],
  optimizedImages: {
    optimizeImages: true
  },
  build: {
    extend (config, ctx) {
    },
    loaders: {
      sass: {
        prependData: '@import "~@/assets/scss/main.scss";'
      }
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: process.env.APP_PORT
  }
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "zimed",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "Zimed - Vue Nuxt App Landing Page Template",
  "author": "Layerdrops",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bazzite/nuxt-optimized-images": "^0.3.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.38.2"
  }
}
```

Which configuration am I missing so that `.scss` files get compiled?

Comment: Can you try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730454/8816585?

Comment: Btw `mode: 'universal'` is deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68272664/8816585

Comment: @kissu thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it is not working. Still getting `$primaryFont` and not the actual value of the variable.

Comment: What if you try `--thm-font: #{$primaryTypography};`? Does it work in the component btw (for debuging purposes)?

Comment: @kissu doing `--thm-font: #{$primaryTypography};`. Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: Not sure if you're missing a word here, I'll suppose that it works with it? I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603882/8816585 Probably that `:root` does have some kind of specific context.

Comment: @kissu adding `body { background-color: $black; }` works. I guess that sass doesn't understand the variable expansion inside `:root` ?!

Comment: @kissu feel free to answer the question so I can accept your answer. Your idea lead me to the solution :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to set SCSS variable to CSS variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202991/unable-to-set-scss-variable-to-css-variable)

Comment: @null The pseudoclass `:root` has no influence on how SASS/SCSS resolves variables. But for css custom properties like `--foo` any value is a valid value and therefore `$some-color` is a valid string value for `--foo`. Hence explicit string interpolation has to be used with `--foo: #{$some-color};`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to interpolate the variable like this `--thm-font: #{$primaryTypography};` in the scope of `:root`.
Not sure the why of this behavior, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603882/8816585) was my way of finding this out.