# Tailwind CSS in Nuxt project trying to use SCSS variable throws "Unknown word" error

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, less, tailwind-css, postcss

I'm using Tailwind CSS in my Nuxt JS project and need to create a simple scss file with some variables that are then used in the `:root` selector to generate some theme colours. I've created my variables, and then have included them inside of my `tailwind.scss` file inside of **assets/scss**

The issue I'm facing is that PostCSS thinks that there's an error with my variable defined in this selector and throws the following error:

> postcss-custom-properties:  Unknown word

To me, this isn't an error as I'm working in a SCSS file which supports variables, what am I missing here?

**assets/scss/tailwind.scss**

```css
@import '../../brand-theme';

/* In your CSS */
:root {
  --color-primary: $primary;
  --color-primary-darken: $primary;
  --color-secondary: $secondary;
}

@import './layout/base';
@import './vendors/hooper';
```

**brand-theme.scss *(in root of my project)* **

```
$primary:    238, 121, 61;
$secondary:  146, 74, 139;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `:root` scope, you need to interpolate the variable as shown in my previous answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68986443/8816585

Like this

```css
--color-primary: #{$primary};
```